# Foundry Vega Plot Work around (too large to transform, limit is 50k)

Tags: palantir-foundry

I have recently created a Vega plot;however, the object size is 500k-3 million. It says the limit is 50k, yikes!

It opens the transform window. I'm trying to make it so when someone selects an object, the vega plot makes the chart of that specific object? I have a workshop app i'm trying to imbed with my vega plot. I don't  see ways in the transform window , aside from pre selecting a specific column/value? The user will ideally click the filter in workshop and see the chart based on the vega plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Add a temporary filter in Quiver that yields an object set of size <=50k objects.
2. Make your Vega Plot
3. Add it to a dashboard, specify inputs/outputs, embed in Workshop
4. In workshop, ensure that for the majority of user experiences the filtered object set will be <=50k
5. Return to Quiver and remove the temporary filter

What I think will happen is that in Quiver you will see the error, but if you have a filter in Workshop that reduces the size of the embedded Quiver Dashboard's input below 50k, then it will work.